# On select/unselect of checkboxes show the add/remove the values in textarea in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, checkbox

In my rails app, a list of record is shown with checkboxes in front of each record and a checkbox to select all the records. I want to add or remove the parents_contact_no data to the text area. On select of checkboxes corresponding record's parents_contact_no should get added to the text area separated by comma and on unselect of the checkbox of corresponding record the corresponding record's parents_contact_no should get removed.
If the select all checkbox is selected than parents_contact_no of all record should get added to the text area.

Text area in which numbers has to be dispayed

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :sent_to %><br>
    <div class="result_div">
      <%= f.text_field :sent_to %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

.html.erb file

```
<% if @contact.empty? %>
    <h4>No records to display</h4>
<% else %>

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><%= check_box_tag "contact_nos[]", @contact.map(&:parents_contact_no) %></th>
          <th>Roll no</th>
          <th>Class</th>
          <th>Section</th>

          <th>Father name</th>

          <th>Parents contact no</th>

          <th colspan="3"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <% @contact.each do |student| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= check_box_tag "contact_no[]", student.parents_contact_no %></td>
            <td><%= student.roll_no %></td>
            <td><%= student.class_name %></td>
            <td><%= student.section %></td>

            <td><%= student.father_name %></td>

            <td><%= student.parents_contact_no %></td>

            <td><%= link_to 'Show', student %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_student_path(student) %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', student, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
<% end %>
```

How to do this via jquery/javascript?

I have added a script which is on change of a checkbox will add/remove the contact in the text area. The problem I am facing is how to get values for current checkbox and put it in the text area.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('[id^=contact_no_]').change(function() {
        alert("checked");
        alert($('input["name=contact_no[]"]:checked').value());
        $('#message_message_text').val("Hello");

    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer to this, the script that worked for me is as follow

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('[id^=contact_no_]').change(function() {
        //alert("checked");
        var checkedValues = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get().join(", ");
        //alert(checkedValues);
        $('#message_sent_to').val(checkedValues);

    });
  });
</script>
```

Explaination : Since we want to grab the id of the checkbox which is going to be in the form contact_no_1 for first record and contact_no_2 for second one and so on. So we get the id with regex expression like id^=contact_no_ and on this we called a change function which will work for select and unselect. Than we took the values in a variable checkedValues for all the checkboxes that are checked and joined the values on the basis of comma. Finally, we added checkeValues variable content to the textarea.